# Android Studio can not run or debug app on emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have a very odd situation here:

I just want to run and debug my app on the emulator.

I get

```
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.myapp"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.myapp
Success
```

The app is correctly installed on the emulator, but does not start up.

- I can run and debug this app on USB-Device.
- I can run and debug any other app on same emulator.
- I tried different AVDs (arm and intel), SDK and Target

Build finishes with 0 errors and 0 warnings. Eventlog is empty. I cleaned the gradle file and changed the only dependency com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+.

I can start the app normally on the AVD by clicking on it's icon.

When I start debugging, app installs, then waits endlessly on:

```
Waiting for process: com.example.myapp
```

I do not even now where to start looking (of course I tried rebuilding, synchronizing and cleaning cache). I also tried changing the project name.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try making a new project and copying your code over?